# Unable to display content below Nav Bar in Html. The "Hello World" should display below navigation bar

Tags: html, css

This hello world doesn't displays. On the inspect element, it appears to be on the top of the page. If I add Hello world before nav ending bracket, then it displays within navigation bar at the relative position to the other elements.

I am using bootstrap.css and my own styles. It should display as shown in image in google drive...
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3RZkWk-pASgelVKSl9LZkZndTQ/view?usp=sharing

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css">

</head>
<style type="text/css">
    .navbar{
    padding-bottom:25px;
    background-color: #808080;
}
 a {
    color: white;

}
.menu{
      margin: auto;
    width: 50%;

    padding: 10px;
}
body,html {
   overflow: hidden;
}

</style>
<!-- Main Body-->

<body>
       <div class="container">
       <!-- Navigation Bar starts-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">

        <div class="container">
        <div class="well"> Smart Campus
        </div>
        </div>
                <div class="menu">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Ideas</a></li>
                      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Communities</a></li>
                      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Knowledge</a></li>
                      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Showcase</a></li>
                      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">News&Events</a></li>
                      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">About</a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
        <div class="menu" >
            <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>




            </div>
        </div>


    </nav>
    <!-- Navigation Bar starts-->
    <!-- But this hello world doesn't displays. On the inspect element, it appears to be on the top of the page.-->
    <div>Hello World</div>

    </div>






</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you copy your code into a fiddle or a code snippet, "Hello World" displays  just below the navbar. Is that not what's supposed to happen?

Answer (score 1):

You're using a fixed position nav, so regularly positioned elements on the page will not have context of where the nav is and will flow underneath it. If you don't need a fixed header, remove `navbar-fixed-top` from the nav classes, then other elements on the page will flow around it as expected.

Otherwise, you can specify a fixed height for the nav, then add that same height as `padding-top` to `body` or your main content section to push the top of those sections below the height of the nav.

I wouldn't recommend doing this because it isn't performant, but another way to address it would be to use javascript or jquery to listen to the page `load` and `resize` events, and on those events get the computed height of the nav, and add that as padding to body or the content section. Here's a demo of that.

```js
$navbar = $('.navbar');
$(window).on('load resize',function() {
  $('body').css('padding-top',$navbar.outerHeight());
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css">

</head>
<style type="text/css">
  .navbar{
    padding-bottom:25px;
    background-color: #808080;
}
 a {
    color: white;

}
.menu{
      margin: auto;
    width: 50%;

    padding: 10px;
}
body,html {
}
</style>
<!-- Main Body-->

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Navigation Bar starts-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">

      <div class="container">
        <div class="well"> Smart Campus
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="menu">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
          <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Ideas</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Communities</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Knowledge</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Showcase</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#">News&Events</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#">About</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="menu">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>


        </div>
      </div>


    </nav>
    <!-- Navigation Bar starts-->
    <!-- But this hello world doesn't displays. On the inspect element, it appears to be on the top of the page.-->
    <div>Hello World</div>

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard without a working code snippet, and copy pasting your code will display "Hello World" so I'm a little bit confused. I separated the nav and the content in two different containers which might.

### Try this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Navigation Bar starts-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="well">
          Smart Campus
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li class="active" role="presentation">
              <a href="#">Ideas</a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation">
              <a href="#">Projects</a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation">
              <a href="#">Communities</a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation">
              <a href="#">Knowledge</a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation">
              <a href="#">Showcase</a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation">
              <a href="#">News&Events</a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation">
              <a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
          <div aria-label="..." class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span></button> <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span></button> <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span></button> <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span></button> <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span></button> <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span></button> <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span></button> <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span></button> <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span></button> <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- Navigation Bar starts-->
    <!-- But this hello world doesn't displays. On the inspect element, it appears to be on the top of the page.-->
    <div class="container">
      <div>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

### I would recommend reading this Bootstrap documentation:

Basic template from: [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template)